# Populate Disabled Field With Date Selected From DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have an `asp.net` `webform` with a `datepicker` (which is working fine) but what I want to do is make the field disabled and show the calendar when they click on the calendar next to the field, then for the selected date to populate the field but I'm unsure on how to do this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="Step03StartDateLabel" class="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Date you would like us to start *" AssociatedControlID="Step03StartDateField"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Step03StartDateField" runat="server" class="form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ID="reqStep03startDateErrorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="Step03StartDateField" ErrorMessage="Please select a date you would want us to start." />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function ()
{
     $("#MainContent_Step03StartDateField").datepicker(
     {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Updated my `HTML` to:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <asp:TextBox ID="Step03StartDateField" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled/>
     <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="Step03StartDateFieldCalendar" style="cursor: pointer"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

And also changed my `JQuery` to:

```
$(function ()
{
     $("#MainContent_Step03StartDateField").datepicker(
     {
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     });

     $("#Step03StartDateFieldCalendar").click(function ()
     {
          $("#MainContent_Step03StartDateField").datepicker("show");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsfiddle link i have found

[image]

[jsfiddle/jquerycalender](https://jsfiddle.net/harishthirunahari/yf2yeeeq/)

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });

Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't display the calendar at all and also when I try this, my calendar image is displayed below my field and not next to it

Comment: Try that fiddle in chrome. i have attached the image also which is showing the calender next to the field.